# Issue with UDP packet sending to a device running Debian

Tags: c++, udp, buffer

I am building a simple UDP sender and receiver using C++ in order to empirically test the limitations of UDP datagram exchanges between devices in a local network.
The previously listed simple applications are respectively built on the following code blocks:

**sender.cpp**

```
[...]
HiResTime start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
for (int i = 0; i < 690 * clients; i++) {
  int bytes = sendto(sockFD, (const char*) buffer.data(), UDP_BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (const struct sockaddr*) &servAddrss, servAddrssLen);  // buffer is a std::vector...
}
HiResTime end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
[...]
```

**receiver.cpp**

```
[...]
HiResTime start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
HiResTime first;
while (n < N) {
  int descr = select(sockFD + 1, &s, NULL, NULL, &t);
  if (descr > 0) {
    if (n == 0) {
      first = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }
    assert(FD_ISSET(sockFD, &s));
    assert(descr == 1);
    int bytes = recvfrom(sockFD, (char*) buffer.data(), UDP_BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &addrss, &addrssLen);
    assert(bytes > 0);
    n++;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Timeout reached!" << '\n';
  }
  s = S;  // Reset fd_set...
  t = T;  // Reset struct timeval...
}
[...]
```

For this test I am using a notebook running Debian and a MacBook running macOS Sierra.

Running respectively the receiver on the MacBook and the sender on the Debian notebook, everything seems fine: it seems that ~22080 UDP packages per second can be managed in this way.
On the other side, running the receiver on the Debian notebook and the sender on the MacBook, it seems the Debian notebook is not able to receive correctly all the packets (I have to run multiple times the sender in order to reach the threshold value on the receiver side).

Why does this happen? Is it due to the different buffer size that the system dedicates for sending/receiving packets? If yes, how can I change the system buffer size in order to improve performances and avoid the above mentioned data loss?

Comment: There is no such thing as UDP connection

Comment: Just because a UDP packet is sent doesn't mean it will be received.

Comment: @Shawn as far as I know, data loss probability between nodes in a local network (in this case, two laptops connected to a router via ethernet cable) is near to zero. This is confirmed when package stream goes from Debian laptop to MacBook. On the other side, when packages are sent from the MacBook to the Debian laptop, almost the 80% of the packages are not received, and so I am wondering if the issue is related to how Debian manages incoming UDP packets and how are they temporarily stored in the buffer memory, before they are read by `recvfrom()`.

Comment: If a computer's networking hardware receives UDP packets faster than the program calling `recv()` can process them, then eventually the receiving UDPs socket's internal receive-buffer will become full, at which point any additionally received packets that cannot fully fit into that buffer will be discarded by the networking stack.  You can try setting the receiving socket's receive-buffer larger (via `setsockopt(fd, SO_RCVBUF, ...)`) and see if that helps.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, taking your suggestion into account, it seems that the macOS send buffer is causing this issue: `perror("sendto()")` sometimes prints `sendto(): No buffer space available`. That said, I have tried to resize `SO_SNDBUF` but the issue persists. Maybe should I resize a different buffer? If yes, which buffer?

Comment: @rudicangiotti I think for that problem it might be enough to simply call `sendto()` again with the same arguments when errno is set to `ENOBUFS` (or `EINTR`).